# 3rd person character not moving in unity.

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have imported Unity Standard assets to Unity 5.6.0, I drag the 3rd person character to the scene, it keeps animating but it does not move on AWSD or Left/Right keys.
This is happening in only one project, it works on all other projects. I have searched from the net, but non of the solution seems to work.

Comment: Can you provide the code with the issue in question?

Answer (score 1):

Just try to reimport the asset with the unity third-person controller the import could have gone wrong in some place or try to build the game under build settings to see if that helped

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue today, even though this thread is ancient.

for me it was because i was using my own camera and did not have the "MainCamera" tag set on it.

Answer (score 0):

Your character controller is made up of multiple pieces (animation files/model/script and possibly other files). There could be a problem with how you are loading the 3rd person character to the scene. I would try creating a prefab of the 3rd person character within a project and then export it as a prefab. Could be missing the script attached to the object as well. The prefab helps prevent you leaving any pieces behind that make up your character/objects. Helpful for level construction as well.

Take a look here if it helps:   https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Prefabs.html

Another possible explanation could be how you have your input settings setup within that Unity Project. Try comparing the two inputs of the working instance, and the non-working instance.

Try looking here for a more detailed approach : https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-InputManager.html

Comment: I am already using 3rd person character prefab in the scene, and it has all the necessary scripts and animator attached, and it is working in all other projects but not in this one.

Comment: Added another possible way. Try looking at the InputManager settings. Are these similar for each of the projects?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too and in the end it was because I had my project set up to run on IOS in Build Settings. I ***Switched Platform*** to macOS and it worked.

Why? It seems that Unity's Virtual Controller expected the input to be from a Mobile Device (seems obvious now) and the CrossPlatformInputManager was not expecting WSAD.

A workaround in IOS mode is to edit the ThirdPersonCharacter/Scripts/ThirdPersonUserControl.cs and replace the `ThirdPersonUserControl.cs` with `Input`

e.g.

`// read inputs
    //float h = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    //float v = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Vertical");
    // read inputs from default input
    float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");`

I found this when I was digging around an realised the Update function in the script was getting called, however `CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal")` was always returning 0.

It might be worth inspecting both at runtime.